# How to prevent Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

On a Rails 7.1 app, I have the form below

```rb
<%= form_with model: @post do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_area :body %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And the related action.

```rb
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.update(post_params)
    ...
  end
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:body)
end
```

When I submit the form, the following parameters are sent to the controller.

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "post"=>{"body"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Post", "id"=>"1"}
```

Is there a way to prevent `Unpermitted parameter` to be raised?

> Unpermitted parameters: :_method, :authenticity_token, :button, :id. Context: { controller: PostsController, action: update, request: #ActionDispatch::Request:0x0000000110733988, params: {"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "post"=>{"body"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Post", "controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1"} }

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Something very strange is going on here. None of these parameters should trigger `Unpermitted parameters`. `:_method` is used internally by Rack to provide HTTP method overrides. `:authenticity_token` is used by the Rails anti-CSRF middleware. `button` and `id` are parsed from the URI and only parameters from the request body should trigger a `Unpermitted parameters` error. I would check if you can replicate the issue in a newly generated Rails app and from there try to figure exactly what it is in your application thats causing this unexpected behavior.

Comment: You could also override the `#update` method in Post and add a breakpoint and check whats actually being passed in. It could be a simple error where the entire params hash is being passed in by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There is [config](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-action-controller-action-on-unpermitted-parameters) for unpermitted parameters

```rb
# To take no action:
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = false
```

```rb
# To emit an `ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument` event
# on the `unpermitted_parameters.action_controller` topic
# and log at the DEBUG level:
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :log
```

```rb
# To raise a ActionController::UnpermittedParameters exception:
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

You can choose needed

Comment: Something very screwey is still going on here as none these parameters should trigger Unpermitted parameters as they are either special params used by Rails/Rack or from the URI.